# how can i parse a string coming from java servlet in android

Tags: android, android-emulator, java-server

In java servlet i need to send a string to the android using httpservlet , and in android i need to parse that string using xml parsing and to show it on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use [XMLReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html) to achieve this in a async task or a background service.
Extract the data and fill appropriate views.
Refer to the [link](http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html) for tutorials and quick start on parsing